# View logs of past logins to the server

Tags: linux, security, debian, unix

I am using a server running the Debian operating system. Is there a way i can check who logged in to the server, i mean the past logins . I would like to do this to monitor the security on the server. Is this information stored somewhere ?

Thank You

Answer (score 5):

The `/var/log/utmp` and `/var/log/wtmp` files store details of logins and logouts. They are described in the [utmp man page](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man5/wtmp.5.php).

You can use the [`last`](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man1/last.1.php) command (in the Debian sysvinit-utils package) to display the logins:

```
# last
me       pts/0        hostname1        Mon Dec 14 15:03   still logged in
someone  pts/0        hostname2        Mon Dec 14 11:12 - 12:20  (01:08)

wtmp begins Tue Dec  1 15:18:32 2009
```

Answer (score 1):

User logins are stored in /var/log/auth.log by default on debian systems

Answer (score 1):

/var/log/auth.log contains authentication information, including logins. Try 'cat /var/log/auth.log | grep ssh' for SSH logins.

Answer (score 1):

Use the "last" command, which shows a list of the last logged in users:

```
last | head -n 10
```

```
man last
```

for more information :)